# Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provid

Tags: java, android, httpclient, http-response-codes

I was trying to upload a image to server. As im new for the android i was trying with the others code.

This is my error:[Error file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZnw6.jpg)

This is my activity file:-

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btpic, btnup;
    private Uri fileUri;
    String picturePath;
    Uri selectedImage;
    Bitmap photo;
    String ba1;
    public static String URL = "http://127.0.0.1/image.php";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cpic);
        btpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickpic();
            }
        });

        btnup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
        btnup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                upload();
            }
        });
    }

    private void upload() {
        // Image location URL
        Log.e("path", "----------------" + picturePath);

        // Image
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);
        byte[] ba = bao.toByteArray();
        ba1 = Base64.encodeToString(ba,Base64.DEFAULT);

        Log.e("base64", "-----" + ba1);

        // Upload image to server
        new uploadToServer().execute();

    }

    private void clickpic() {
        // Check Camera
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // Open default camera
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Camera not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            selectedImage = data.getData();
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            // Cursor to get image uri to display

            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Imageprev);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }

    public class uploadToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setMessage("Wait image uploading!");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("base64", ba1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ImageName", System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" + st);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }
            return "Success";

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pd.hide();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }}
```

gradle page:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKPMm.jpg)

Comment: call `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5'` or `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.1'`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using target sdk as `23`

then inside the `build.gradle` add:

```
    android
    {
         useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    }
```

as Apache Http is deprecated with the arrival of Marshmallow.

And according to this question, **do not** use any of these gradle files as it seems broken,

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5.1'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It was showing an error message that                                              E:\Internship work\MY projects\Upload_img\app\build.gradle
Warning:Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Comment: You need to download Android 6 SDK in SDK Manager for that.

Answer (score 0):

Way 1:

You need to use in build.gradle

```
android{
   useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

If you use latest version of android SDK.

Way 2:

Use **HttpURLConnection** class instead of **HTTPClient**. **HttpURLConnection** is more efficient than **HTTPClient**.